# Optimizing big SQL migrations

Tags: sql, query-optimization, static-analysis

Is there a tool that detects "inverse" operations (like add column/table in the beginning, drop it later) in a big (1800 statements) migration script?

Comment: You want to do this just once, or you want to check many scripts?

Comment: I don't know if a tool like this exists. I'll poke around but I feel like this would generate a large amount of false positives because adding and dropping tables is a pretty common way to deal with data transformations and such.

Comment: You can compare databases with the Visual Studio schema comparer, if you make a backup of your DB, run the migration script and compare the updated DB with the backup, you'll get "inverse" script.

Comment: sql server projects in visual studio 2012. use source control to keep a "before" and "after"

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool that is all about 'revision' control for your database, for automating both structural changes and data migrations as part of your application upgrade process. I have used this tool successfully and with great effect for a number of years. I cannot recommend it highly enough.

http://www.liquibase.org/